# Order by query output column

Tags: sqlalchemy, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

I'm using graphene with sqlalchemy and I have an output object that contains a computed field. The field is computed according to some input (query) parameter and more or less look like this (to simplify, lets consider I'm computing *f(x)=ax+b* where *a* and *b* are both columns in my
`Thing` table):

```py
import models

class Thing(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Thing
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

    f = graphene.Field(graphene.Float)

    def resolve_f(self, info):
        return self.a * info.context['x'] + self.b
```

In my query I have the following and I would like to sort fields according to the output of the function `f`:

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    best_points = graphene.List(lambda: Thing, x = graphene.Float())

    def resolve_best_points(self, info, x):
        query = Thing.get_query(info)
        return query.all()
```

At first I've tried sorting within `resolve_best_points` using something like `query.order_by("f").all()` but in vain since graphene seems to add this field outside the resolver (ie., `query.all()` only contains `a` and `b` but not `f(a, b)`).

Is there a way to achieve this in a clean way? Adding some option in `Thing`? Or maybe obtaining the output values within the resolver and then sorting? Or something a bit uglier like adding a middleware to sort outputs from `resolve_best_points`?

What is possible, what are the pros/cons of possible solutions to this?

Note that this is somewhat related to this question: [*Sqlalchemy order by calculated column*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966163/sqlalchemy-order-by-calculated-column), but this is also quite different because here I don't want a calculation based on database fields only (current solutions do not work when there are variables involved, like `info.context['x']` in this toy example).

Comment: This is also my question. The thing is that we cannot access the data which are generated at the lower level, from the top level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLAlchemy's `orm.with_expression` and `orm.query_expression` functions to apply ad-hoc expressions to your query, then use them in the `ORDER_BY` clause.

Add a `query_expression` attribute to your `Thing` model.

```py
# models.py
from sqlalchemy import Float, Integer, orm

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'things'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = Column(Float)
    b = Column(Float)

    expr = orm.query_expression()
```

You can now use `with_expression` to pass arbitrary SQL expressions to your queries. The value of the `expr` attribute, on `Thing` objects, will be the result of the expression.

```py
# schema.py
import graphene

from graphene import relay
from sqlalchemy.orm import with_expression

from models import Thing as ThingModel


class Thing(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ThingModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)


class Query(graphene.ObjectType)
    best_points = graphene.List(Thing, x=graphene.Float())

    def resolve_best_points(self, info, x):
        expr = ThingModel.a * x + ThingModel.b

        return (
            Thing.get_query(info)
            .options(with_expression(ThingModel.expr, expr))
            .order_by(expr)
            .all()
        )
```

More details and a list of caveats to be aware of are in this section of the SQLAlchemy docs: [Query-time SQL expressions as mapped attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes).